Factorize a polynomial of degree 6
The task is to factorize the polynomial
$$
f(x)=2x^6+3x^5-63x^4-55x^3+657x^2+216x-2160.
$$
Is there some reasonable easy way to do that by hand?
For example Horner's scheme? For me this looks difficult to do it by hand...

I tried to do that but $2160$ has so many factors...

So I tried the factors $x=1,2,3$. The first one working was $x=3$. So I did Horner's scheme with $x=3$, giving me $(x-3)\cdot(2x^5+9x^4-36x^3-163x^2+168x+720)$. Next; I repeat the procedure with the new polynomial, i.e. testing again which factor of 720 works and so on?

Make sure to check for repeated roots. (One root is of order $3$, while another root is of order $2$.)

As mentioned in comments, trying Rational Root Theorem first is a good bet, especially for textbook, test and contest problems as the authors are usually considerate (real life unfortunately not so much).
If you want to speed up the process, sometimes the following tips work:

Check with Descartes' rule to find if there are positive or negative roots, if you are lucky it may help.  In this case, there are an odd number of sign changes for $p(x)$ and $p(-x)$, so there is ast least one positive and one negative root.  So to find the first root, you may want to focus on any one sign.
Alternately, you can test for multiple root possibilities in one shot - like to test for $x=\pm1$, find the remainder when $x^2-1$ is the divisor.  Substituting $x^2=1$ reduces $f(x)$ to $164x-1564$ from which it is evident that neither $\pm1$ is a root. Similarly $f \pmod {x^2-4}\equiv 44x-412$, so $x=\pm2$ is also ruled out.  OTOH, $f \pmod{x^2-9}\equiv 108-36x$, and so $x=3$ is a root. You can now divide $x-3$ out and continue on the remaining factors, say with $x^2-16$ next.
Once a root is found, you can test if it is also a root of $f', f''$ etc. in sequence to discover if it is a multiple root.

Hope some of these tips help, though some grunt work is inevitable if the person who put up the question wants you persevere and you aren't lucky with the initial trials.

With $$2160 = 2^4 \times 3^3 \times 5,$$ equal to the overall factor $a$ and the product of roots in
$$P_6(x)= a\ (x-x_1)\cdots (x-x_6) = a  \  x^6 + \dots -   a \ (x_1+\dots +x_6) \ x^5 + \dots + a \  x_1 \cdots  x_6.$$ There are 6-8 factors in $$2160 = 2^4 \times 3^3 \times 5 = a \times x_1 \times \dots \times x_6$$
Since $(x\pm 5 )$ does not divide $P_6$ without reminder, try $2x - 5$ which is working. Then there a left 7 prime factors to be grouped to yield the remaining 5 roots. By simplity and laziness of the teachers,  starting the search with powers of linear roots:   $(x \pm3)^3$ and  $(x\pm 4)^2$ as the remaining root factors.
In higher order cases one may consult the linear term
$$216 = a (x_1 +\dots +x_6) $$ To further reduce the divisibility equations and the sign distribution.

How do you conclude from $2160=2^4\cdot 3^5\cdot 5$ that it is worth trying $2x-5$ as well as $(x\pm 3)$ and $(x\pm 4)$? Did not get that.
